# In C#, how could I correctly overload this constructor?

Tags: java, c#, constructor, constructor-overloading

I have a question about the following two constructors which are both part of a [Graph class](http://algs4.cs.princeton.edu/41undirected/Graph.java.html) I'm trying to port over from Java:

```
    public Graph(int V)
    {
        this.m_V = V; this.m_E = 0;
        adj = new Bag<int>[V];
        for (int v = 0; v < V; v++)
            adj[v] = new Bag<int>();
    }
    public Graph(TextReader inpt) : this(int.Parse (inpt.ReadLine()))
    {
        //int V = int.Parse (inpt.ReadLine());
        int E = int.Parse (inpt.ReadLine());
        //this(V);
        for (int i = 0; i < E; i++)
        { // Add an edge.
            string[] inputs = inpt.ReadLine ().Split (' ');
            int v = int.Parse (inputs [0]);
            int w = int.Parse (inputs [1]);
            addEdge(v, w);
        }
    }
```

As it is written,and agreeably it's not pretty, the second constructor will call the first with the first argument V, which is as it should be.

My question is, what would happen if V were the second integer in the input sequence(meaning that I would have to call ReadLine() twice), and how would a similar constructor chaining call look in that case? And, would chaining even be possible without exporting some of the logic into another method?

**Edit**
The main question, and I guess I'm realizing it as this discussion is going on, is about the flexibility of the constructor in C# versus the java one. For example I can call `this(v)` in java after I call `ReadLine()` twice, but how can I achieve the same in C#?

Comment: Calling `ReadLine` in a constructor seems like a REALLY bad idea.

Comment: Agreed, but I'm just wondering how I could translate between the commented out javaish code to C#.

Comment: `without exporting some of the logic into another method?` Sounds like you already know *exactly* how to do this.  Extract it out into a method.  Bam, done.  Or you could just not be cruel and don't do this at all, as has been suggested.  Personally I'd suggest a static factory method over a constructor for that case.

Comment: The main question, and I guess I'm realizing it as this discussion is going on, is about the flexibility of the constructor in C# versus the java one. For example I can call `this(v)` in java after I call `ReadLine()` twice, but how can I achieve the same in C#?

Comment: @rivanov You can't.  By design.  You've found a way to hack your way around it, kinda, sorta, by being evil.  So you now have the choice between being evil, or altering your design more fundamentally.

Comment: Ok, this is kinda meta, and I know I'm not supposed to talk about it, (please tell me where to post about it if that's the case) but why am I getting downvoted so much on this? It's a legitimate design question, no?

Comment: @rivanov Perhaps because you already know of several *good* ways of solving this problem, and you're choosing to ignore them in search of a *terrible* solution for the problem, for no particularly good reason.  Of course, I can only guess.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/78121/discussion-between-rivanov-and-servy).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Warning, the code you are about to see is not suitable for most viewers.

The code shown here is purely for entertainment purposes, and should not be used in actual production code.

If you *really* want to run arbitrary code, in line, before the call to the other constructor, you can do so by embedding an anonymous method that is immediately executed.

```
public class EvilGraph
{
    public EvilGraph(int V)
    {
        //...
    }
    public EvilGraph(TextReader inpt)
        : this(new Func<int>(() =>
        {
            inpt.ReadLine();
            return int.Parse(inpt.ReadLine());
        })())
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

As far as how you should *actually* solve this problem; this shouldn't be a constructor.  It should be a static factory method that can do some work, construct a `Graph` using the actual graph constructor, and then do some additional processing on that `Graph` before returning it to the caller.  This removes all concern about when, during this construction process, other constructor calls need to be.

Comment: Thanks for shining some light onto my naive brain! I would never have though of a static factory, because I really don't know design patterns that well(perhaps I should've mentioned this in the post)

Comment: @rivanov Whether you know what name a particular pattern might be called by isn't really important here.  All you need is a static method; it doesn't even need to be in another class (in fact, I'd say it doesn't even belong in another class).  While there are names for this pattern, you don't *really* need to know or care about any of that, just use your static method to construct the object.